# Why is Raphael.js animating to incorrect coordinates?

Tags: javascript, raphael

I'm trying to do a simple animation in Raphael.js in which a paper.text object is moved from its current position to another position. Here is some of my code (there is far too much to post all of it):

```
songPos = getSongPosition(this, charIndex);
letter.path.animate({x: songPos.x, y: songPos.y, "font-size": this.correctFontSize}, 500, onAnimationComplete);
```

Here is the Letter object being referenced in the above code:

```
function Letter(args)
{
    this.letter = args.letter || "A";
    this.correct = args.correct || false;
    this.transformation = args.transformation || "";
    this.initX = args.x || 0;
    this.initY = args.y || 0;
    this.path = null;
}

Letter.prototype.buildPath = function()
{
    this.path = paper.text(this.initX, this.initY, this.letter);
    if(this.transformation)
    {
        this.path.transform(this.transformation);
    }
    return this;
};
```

The problem is I'm printing the `x` and `y` values returned by `getSongPosition`, and they're correct, but the animate method is sending my text object somewhere off-screen. I've also tried just setting the animation attributes to `{x: 0, y: 0}`, but I still get the same results. I can post more of the code if it is necessary.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE 1:** 
Part of my program requires I be able move objects to specific coordinates. Some of the objects will be rotated and others will not, so I wrote this:

```
Letter.prototype.getMoveTransform = function(x, y)
{
    var bbox = this.path.getBBox(true);
    var dx = x - bbox.x;
    var dy = y - bbox.y;
    return "T" + dx + "," + dy + (this.transformation == null ? "" : this.transformation);
};
```

I believe this is the root of my problem. This function is supposed to generate the transformation required to move a rotated object to (x, y). I'm not sure why I have to re-rotate the object on every animation.

**UPDATE 2:**
I have somehow solved my problem. I would post my solution, but I don't understand why any of this works/didn't work in the first place anymore.

Comment: To help you here, it would be useful if you could recreate the animation part of your code using jsfiddle.net

Comment: I've tried to reproduce my problem on jsfiddle, but I cannot. I believe I've found the stem of my problem, so I'll update my question.

Comment: Raphael doesn't remember your previous transforms when you do a new one I don't think, you have to cater for any previous transforms yourself

Answer (score 1):

this.path.getBBox(true); should be this.path.getBBox() or this.path.getBBox(false);

you need get transformed position every time to calculate the dx and dy

Comment: I was actually able to get my animations working by changing `dx = x - bbox.x` to `dx = x - bbox.x - bbox.width/2`.